# Typescript & Gatsby: Development bundle cannot resolve paths but VS Code can

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, gatsby

I have a bunch of imports like `import Navi from 'components/Navi'`

These have a red error line under the `components/Navi` part until I add this to my `tsconfig.json`

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
  "layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"],
  "pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
  "templates/*": ["src/templates/*"],
  "scss/*": ["src/scss/*"],
  "types": ["src/types"]
}
```

At which point the error goes away. When I try to build my develop bundle through running `gatsby develop` everything looks fine until this appears `⠹ Building development bundle`

Which is followed shortly by lots of statements like `Can't resolve 'components/Navi' in '~/src/components'`

And these errors only go away when I specify a relative path like `import Navi from '../Navi'`

---

As a side note, I also can't do `import {MyType} from 'types'` with a structure of

```
src
    -> types
        -> index.ts
```

It gives an error with a red line under the word `'types'` which states `Cannot find module 'types'.ts(2307)` And I must change the import to `import {Issue} from 'types/index'`

---

I already tried running `gatsby clean` and deleting `node_modules`

Comment: TypeScript's `paths` option is used to inform the TypeChecker that loaders or bundlers _will make_ modules available via the specified mappings, it does not make those files available. In other words it is for specifying behavior of other tools.

Comment: so how do I make those files available

Comment: Depends on the tool, I think gatsby is using Webpack under the hood. If so you need to configure webpack to resolve modules using the analogous rules. See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/ and  and https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/. Typically, you would configure Webpack or whatever tool first and then setup paths to match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [`gatsby-plugin-root-import`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-root-import/) to your gatsby-config.js in order to make use of absolute imports.

Webpack 4 provided alias in its config whereby you can specify absolute imports from a specific folder. [`gatsby-plugin-root-import`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-root-import/) plugin helps you achieve that config

First install it using

```
npm install --save-dev gatsby-plugin-root-import
```

or

```
yarn add --dev gatsby-plugin-root-import
```

and then configure it in gatsby-config.js like below

```js
// gatsby-config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ...
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-root-import',
      options: {
        "components": path.join(__dirname, "src/components"),
        "layouts": path.join(__dirname, "src/layouts"),
        "templates": path.join(__dirname, "src/templates"),
        "scss": path.join(__dirname, "src/scss"),
        "types": path.join(__dirname, "src/types"),
        "src": path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        "pages": path.join(__dirname, 'src/pages')
      }
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: It seems to work with everything but interfaces. The site renders fine, but there's a red line under `import { Request } from "interfaces/requests.interface"` with the error `Cannot find module 'interfaces/requests.interface'.ts(2307)` is given I have `"paths" {..."interfaces": ["src/interfaces/*"],...}` in my tsconfig.json and `options: {..."interfaces": path.join(__dirname, "src/interfaces"),...}}` under `gatsby-plugin-root-import` in my gatsby-config.json

Comment: Are you sure interfaces are in src folder

Comment: Also in tsConfig, would would need `"interfaces/*": ["src/interfaces/*"],`. Notice the `/*`. Maybe try to rename your interface files with `.ts` extension

Answer (score 3):

Shubham's solution still works as of June 2021 - if you want it automatically resolve all dirs under `src`, you can use a little two-liner I wrote for this:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const srcDirs = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "src"));

const rootDirsConfig = {};

srcDirs.forEach((srcDir) => {
    rootDirsConfig[srcDir] = path.resolve(__dirname, "src", srcDir);
});

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-root-import",
            options: rootDirsConfig,
          },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Antoni Papiewski's answer still works.

If you use TypeScript, then just add `IPluginRefOptions` type to rootDirsConfig. Like this:

```
import { IPluginRefOptions } from 'gatsby';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

const srcDirs = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'));

const rootDirsConfig: IPluginRefOptions = {};

srcDirs.forEach((srcDir) => {
  rootDirsConfig[srcDir] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', srcDir);
});
```